# How to disable Google search result link redirect (on right-click) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

When logged in to Google, Google search results are redirected (for tracking purposes etc.). This is annoying, as it's not easy to copy/paste the URL without visiting the site. If there would be no redirect, I would just right-click the link in the search results and select "Copy link address". Now it is altered by some Google JavaScript code which monitors for the right-click.

How can this be disabled on Chrome? 
I think there used to be a Chrome extension for it, but seems to not be working anymore.

Comment: What is the purpose of your right-click?

Comment: @Beniamin: as said in my question: "copy [paste] the URL". I just want to get the URL (e.g. for pasting in a report etc.)

Comment: FYI: Just selecting the text with the cursor and pressing ctrl-c is not always an option, because google concatenates long URLs

Comment: Ok. But when you right-click on link, it changes to google tracking link. So you won't get that link unless you open page, google will redirect you to desired page and you will have what you want.

Comment: The question is exactly on how to avoid that. (there was some chrome extension before (doesn't work anymore), and some greasemonkey script for firefox, but last time I checked I had some issues with that. So saying "you won't get that link unless you open the page" doesn't make sense).

Comment: I edited my answer so it should work with Google Instant. Check it out.

Answer (score 8):

Now when I know what you wanted, I wrote a little script which deletes `onmousedown` attribute from link.

Here it is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Delete onmousedown
// @namespace      google
// @include        http://www.google.*/*
// ==/UserScript==
var runOnce = function(){
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('li.g h3.r a');
    for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i< len; i++){
        items[i].removeAttribute('onmousedown');
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).innerHTML = "("+runOnce+")()";
```

Save it as some file which ends with .user.js and drop it on Google Chrome and let me know if it helped.

PS. English is not my spoken language so sorry for misunderstanding you.

Edit: I added extra logic so it should work with Google Instant. Tell me if it works for you.

Edit: I rolled back to version "without" Google Instant support.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried something similar, however, when I drag the script file over Chrome, it is opened in the browser, displaying the source code instead of installing the script.

Comment: Try Ctrl+O to open the file. And are you sure you named it something like: google.user.js?

Comment: And I've read that chrome window need to be maximized.

Comment: Or install some greasemonkey-like extension in chrome. It will help you install scripts and greasemonkey scripts should work. For example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Comment: Hmm, I got it installed, but it isn't working. When I inserted some alert messages to troubleshoot, I noticed that it runs when I go to www.google.com (I changed the @include), but as I typed my query, the google page is rewritten using google's javascript, and of course the greasmonkey script isn't rerun :-(

Comment: @Rabarberski, then you’ll have to stop using Google Instant.

Comment: @Synetech: indeed, forgot that I could do that. Is working now. Kind of stupid though that Google makes this so hard.

Comment: Your edited version (for google instant) doesn't seem to be working for me. But I was happy to disable Google Instant and use your previous version

Comment: This is great. I only needed to change http:// to https://. I think Google always use https. If it is not, you can duplicate include line and change one to https to cover both http and https urls.

Comment: @Beniamin - Where is the Reflexiv thing you pointed to? Its not on this page?

Comment: @Beniamin - ?? Unclear what you said

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot edit it now :). 
I was saying that I was referring to answer, written by Reflexiv, which is now probably removed as I cannot find it. So I removed a reference to that answer from my answer. Sorry for typos.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use ["Undirect" Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undirect/dohbiijnjeiejifbgfdhfknogknkglio).

> It removes this tracking and redirection from google search results. Supports using google over both HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Firefox**, you are lucky as the following answer applies to you. If you are using Chrome, you are much less lucky, see the bottom of this answer.

Greasemonkey fires the user scripts [once the DOM is loaded](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded), thus you don't need to implement a "DOM ready" listener.

Also you are on Firefox, so you can use some modern candy: [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Here is the resulting Greasemonkey script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove Google redirects
// @namespace   google
// @description Remove redirects from Google Search result links.
// @include     https://www.google.*/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

for (let element of document.querySelectorAll('#res .r > a')) {
    element.removeAttribute('onmousedown');
}
```

Thanks to the `let` there are no local declarations, therefore you don't need to enclose the above code in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

---

For the unfortunate **Chrome** (Tampermonkey) users:

Links are not found at the time the script is executed, even though `document.readyState === 'complete'`… as a result you have to implement some loop with timer.

Therefore, you end up with:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove Google redirects
// @namespace   google
// @description Remove redirects from Google Search result links.
// @include     https://www.google.*/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function removeGoogleRedirects() {

    var links = document.querySelectorAll('#res .r > a');

    if (links.length === 0) {
        setTimeout(removeGoogleRedirects, 100);
        return;
    }

    for (var link of links) {
        link.removeAttribute('onmousedown');
    }

})();
```

---

Update October 2018:
Because of a markup change in the Google page, the `h3.r` needed to be changed to `div.r`.
I went farther and replaced `h3.r > a` with `#res .r > a` (replaced "tag.class" with just ".class", and added a parent as a security so that the selector is not too generic).

Comment: Taking the text of the Firefox script, and appending 'javascript: ' to the start of it, and then making a bookmarklet of it (a la bobobobo's answer) worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I like @bobobobo's answer but unfortunately, it didn't work for me on Chromium Edge.

However, the following bookmarklet did work just fine:

```javascript
javascript: const items = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (const i of items) { if ( i.onmousedown || i.getAttribute('data-ved') ) {i.removeAttribute("onmousedown");i.removeAttribute("data-ved")} }
```

I also remove the `data-ved` attribute as I suspect that is also involved with tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin's script works for me if I change the selector to: `li.g div.vsc h3.r a`

Actually this user script looks like it would do the job:

[Google Tracking-B-Gone for Greasemonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47300)

Answer (score 0):

I find this scriptlet easiest to run. Copy and drag it to your bookmarks bar and click it *before* right clicking on any of the search result links.

```
javascript: var items = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  for( var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++ )  if( items[i].className=='l' )  items[i].onmousedown = null ;
```

God these people are satan but I updated the script Beniamin gave, works as of the date of this post.  User [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706757/is-there-a-way-to-check-document-ready-if-jquery-is-not-available) to lightweight make sure page has loaded before stripping a elements of their mousedown events.  Must use [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) to make this work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Delete onmousedown
// @namespace      google
// @version        0.1
// @description    Allows you to right click links on Google search results without having them mangled on you.
// @include          http://www.google.*/*
// ==/UserScript==
var tid = setInterval( function () {
    if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;

    var items = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    var succeeded=false;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++ )
    {
      if( items[i].className=='l' )
      {
        if( items[i].onmousedown ) { succeeded=true; } // we stripped the urls
        items[i].onmousedown = null ;
      }
    }

    if( succeeded )  clearInterval( tid ); // stop invoking this routine when we succeeded.
}, 100 );
```

Comment: That bookmarklet didn't work for me on Chromium Edge.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Web Store extension [Don't Track Me Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg?hl=en) works perfectly for me in Chromium Edge. There is no more funny business from google.com with the URL changing when you click on it.